# Angular Material - Dynamic Load not rendering properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Component which is loaded dynamically using `Angular 15` and `Angular Material`, the Component manages to load and is displayed on screen, however, it is not procesing the `Angular Material` selectors and this is what is displayed on screen:
[image]

However, I setup the very same code in Stackblits and it works perfectly fine there and this is what it displays:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-rubl8b

Then I try a new `Angular` project from scratch on my desktop and the same code does not work. I also tried downloading the code from `Stackblits` and it simply does not install the `npm` dependencies and if I force the installation, it does not compile.

Any idea why is this happening?

The complete code is in `Stackblits`, if you want to reproduce the issue try creating a new project in your desktopm using:

```
1. ng new angular-dynamic-second
2. npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
3. ng add @angular/material
```

Comment: do you see any errors on the development console when the Component is loaded?

Comment: @yo_sup No, no message, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem locally on my computer.

### Problem

You attempted to create a dynamic component using an approach that doesn't work. It creates a new instance of `Component` and passes it some metadata describing the component, but it doesn't actually define any properties or methods for the component class.

### Solution

The code below creates a dynamic component by using the `@ViewChild` decorator to get a reference to a `ViewContainerRef` object and then using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to create a new instance of the `DynamicComponent`. The `DynamicComponent` is a simple component with an `inputValue` property and a template that displays a `mat-form-field` from Angular Material.

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-dynamic-second",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-dynamic-second": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-dynamic-second",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-dynamic-second:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-dynamic-second:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-dynamic-second:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import '@angular/compiler';

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularDynamicSecond</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example/example.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-dynamic-second';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-example></app-example>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**example.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  container!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  loadModule() {
    this.container.clear();
    const componentFactory =
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    componentRef.instance.inputValue = 'Hello World!';
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-component',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
      <input matInput maxlength="10" />
      <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="true">
        First Name is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
  styles: [''],
  imports: [NgIf, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class DynamicComponent {
  inputValue: string = '';
}
```

**example.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary"> Angular Material App </mat-toolbar>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="loadModule()">Load Module</button>

<ng-container #container></ng-container>

<mat-slide-toggle color="primary">Slide Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>
```

**Folder structure:**

[image: Structure]

Comment: Thank you Rok foir the detailed answer. I know this approach you describe works (I have tested it). However, perhaps I didn't mention that one key requirement is that, the `template` of the component  needs to be variable, that is why I have written the `Component` inside the `loadModule()` block. I have also tried `SystemJS`, the component is loaded, but with the same result, the material components are not wired-up properly. The only place I have seen the material components wired-up is in Stackblits. Anyways, do you know any other approach to do the this?

Comment: @JoeAlmore I'm trying but can't get it to work. Have you figure out anything in the meantime?

Comment: I am still on it. I also posted the bug in the Angular Repo at github, but still no response from the Angular team. But, did you manage to reproduce the issue in your Desktop?

Comment: @JoeAlmore Yes, I did. The output was exactly the same as in your first screenshot. I'll try to find a solution.